# Why is width/height respected in accordance to normal flow for inline-block

Tags: css

Why does setting a width/height and padding etc. work with `display: inline-block` compared to `display: inline` ? To my understanding, internally `display: inline-block` has an outer display type of `inline` and inner display type of `flow-root`, and `display: inline` has an outer display type of `inline` and innerdisplay type of `flow`. I don't understand the connection in how setting the inner display type to `flow-root` contributes to making an `inline-block` element have its width/height etc. respected as part of normal flow. Setting a width and height changes an element's box model's width and height, but its outer display type is still inline. This means the element still participates in its parent's inline formatting context, where its box model width/height etc don't take up space in normal flow.

e.g the `.inline` p element is allowed to change its box model's padding, but the change in box model width/height doesn't cause it to take space in normal flow, so even though the box model gets bigger, it doesn't push other boxes down.

However, changing the padding of the `.inline-block` p element does make it take up space in normal flow.

I don't see how understand how changing an inner type to `flow-root` makes elements with `display: inline-block` suddenly have their width/height etc. respected as part of normal flow since their outer display type is still inline.

```css
.inline {
  display: inline;
  padding: 30px ;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="inline">
  inline
  </p>
  This is some filler text
</div>
<div>
  <p class="inline-block">
  inline-block
  </p>
  This is some filler text
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are overthinking about this. The Spec detail each case: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html and inline-block are different from inline. They have similarities but they are not 100% the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all behaviour is captured by either the display inside or outside types on their own, and it's definitely not as simple as flow versus flow-root.

We can categorise inline-level elements into two types, those that for which height and width apply and vertical padding and margins affect the line box height on the one hand, and those which don't on the other.

In the first category we have

```
display: values                  │ inner display type 
─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────
inline (replaced elements)       │ not defined in CSS¹
inline-block                     │ flow-root
inline-table                     │ table
inline-flex                      │ flex
inline-grid                      │ grid
```

In the second category we have

```
display: values                  │ inner display type 
─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────
inline (non-replaced elements)   │ flow
inline list-item                 │ flow
ruby                             │ ruby
```

The types in first category have several other common traits. They are atomic (don't get fragmented across line boxes), opaque (their contents do not affect the layout of peer boxes, except by exposing a baseline) and establish an independent formatting context for their contents.

None of these traits are shared by the second category. The set of traits seem to come as a package for inline-level elements, but the specifications just identify which category applies in each case without naming the categories.

I'm not sure this helps you, but I thought it was worth laying out the fuller picture.

---

<sub>¹ Actually, all inline-level replaced elements (including those assigned `display:ruby`) have an inner display type undefined in CSS, and belong to the first category.</sub>